# MySQL Crosstab Query by Month returning default of 1's?

Tags: mysql

Why is my query returning "1's" when I'm telling it to default to "0" if there are no values for that month?

Here's my results:
[image]

```
SELECT  td_type,

COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Jan',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%02') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Feb',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%03') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Mar',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%04') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Apr',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%05') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'May',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%06') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Jun',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%07') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Jul',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%08') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Aug',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%09') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Sep',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%10') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Oct',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%11') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Nov',
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ttDate,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%12') THEN (ttNum)    ELSE    0   END ) AS 'Dec',
            COUNT(ttNum) AS Total

FROM      v_closed_tickets
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(ttDate, '%Y%') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%')) AND ttCategory IN ('TT') 

GROUP BY ccOption
```

Comment: Never mind mine last (deleted) comment.. Show table structure and example data place it on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com.. Besides you know you are misusing MySQL GROUP BY feature? By selecting a column which is not in the GROUP BY clause.. That why you should also include expected results as formatted text.

Comment: `count(distinct 0)` counts the number of distinct values. There is 1 distinct value (namely the value 0), or none if your select does not return any row. It's hard to figure out what you are after (maybe remove the `else`-part completely?), so, as Raymond said, provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Thanks guys.. removing the ELSE 0 did the trick!